# How to grab local directory of the file that was input in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's what i want to do:

Input any file onto my blob container 'myContainer' using MVC:

```
   <!--File Uploader-->

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home",
                       FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-    data" }))
   {
    <div>Please select an image to upload</div>
<input name="image" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
   }
```

The above code asks for a file, when you select any file-it's directory shows up on the textbox, great right? now with that directory i can THEORETICALLY input it onto the code below

```
// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\X\asdf.txt")) //I manually entered the directory of a certain file
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

When this code runs and has the full directory of the file i want to upload, the file uploads!

So what's the problem?

Well, how exactly do i get the directory? First of all, the code above has a full directory already, but i dont want to specify it, i want my html to do it automatically, understand?

I dont want to manually specify the directory of the file i want to upload, i want to grab the file directory automatically from my form ('exDirectory') and set it onto the upload code:

```
 // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@exDirectory)) //'exDirectory' should have any directory of any file input
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

Summary, i cant upload any file unless i manually specify it's directory, i NEED code that can automatically grab any file's directory that is input from the html razor code.

Comment: It seems you are completely misunderstanding how file upload works on the web, as well as confusing local file system with remote.

Comment: you realize the difference between server-side and client-side, right? also: some (many) browsers abstract away the details of the client-side path, so you'll never know them

Comment: You clearly searched and found that you can not get folder of file uploaded from browser, but even if you would - how path from user's machine would help to save file on server?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov using azure.storage.blob code, with a local directory i can upload that file onto my blob container

Comment: @FluffyWuffy no, you can't; you have no access to the client-side directory; all you have is the file that the browser sent *as part of the request*

Comment: ok i see what you mean